How to remove new line character from Latex template if data is not available
Original question in Tex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719107/how-to-remove-new-line-character-from-latex-template-if-data-is-not-available?noredirect=1#comment1787948_719107
But I have been told it is not directly related to Tex, so posting it here
I am using Python and jinja2 to populate some data in my Latex template and then convert it to PDF using Latex. Here is the template:
my_tample = r"""
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C @{}}
\Huge{ {{ data.name }} } \\\\[7.5pt]
\href{https://github.com/{{ data.github_username }}}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faGithub\ {{ data.github_username }}} \ $|$ \ 
\href{https://linkedin.com/in/{{ data.linkedin_username }}}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faLinkedin\ {{ data.linkedin_username }}} \ $|$ \ 
\href{ {{ data.website_url }}}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faGlobe \ {{ data.website_url | replace('https://', '') }}} \ $|$ \ 
\href{mailto:{{ data.email }}}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faEnvelope \ {{ data.email }}} \ $|$ \ 
\href{tel:{{ data.phone }}}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faMobile \ {{ data.phone }}} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
"""

This works fine and no errors, however, I want to add this functionality: If any of the data is Null then dont include it. So if website_url is not provided, then do not display the website icon with empty link.
This is what I tried: I can do something like this:
{% if data.website_url %} \href{ {{ data.website_url }}}{\raisebox{-0.05\height}\faGlobe \ {{ data.website_url | replace('https://', '') }}} \ $|$ \  {% endif %}

But the problem is, if the website url is not provided, then all of the following icons such as email and phone will be displayed in next line, I dont want this, I want to keep them all in the same line, just take away the icons that do not have data.

If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/719107/36296

Thank you for mentioning it @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I posted the question there and I have been told it is not related to Tex, it is related to Python and Jinja and I have been advised to post it here.

If its is not a latex problem, you should delete your question on tex.se and safe the community there from having to close it.

maybe you need {% else %} to put some Tex with empty line. {% if ... %} ... {% else %} ... {% endif %}
